# How to get a location from an AVD?

Tags: android, geolocation, google-play-services

I writed a sample code to test only if location works on an AVD Nexus 4 API 19. I did not find any answers for my simple code.

checkPlayServices() is ok (return 0) and mGoogleApiClient is created but i get null from

```
LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)
```

Is it possible to get a location from an virtual device ? I simulated one with a telnet geo fix but it does not works (it is for LocationManager...).

Thank's for help

```
   ...
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (checkPlayServices()) {
        buildGoogleApiClient();
    }
}

protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient(){
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(LocationServices.API)
            .build();

    mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi
            .getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

    if (mLastLocation != null) {
        double latitude = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
        double longitude = mLastLocation.getLongitude();
    } else {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                "This device is not supported.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                .show();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you use the Google API version in your AVD?

Comment: I have the same problem with the avd api 19 with google play api.

Answer (score 0):

Using the Emulator Control Window withing DDMS. Send test locations.

Setting the location of the phone

If your application depends on the location of the phone, you can have DDMS send your device or AVD a mock location. This is useful if you want to test different aspects of your application's location specific features without physically moving. The following geolocation data types are available to you:

Manual - set the location by manually specifying decimal or sexagesimal longitude and latitude values.
GPX - GPS eXchange file
KML - Keyhole Markup Language file

For more information about providing mock location data, see Location Strategies. [Android Docs](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html)

Good Luck.

Comment: Thank's for the answer, i found the Emulator Control Windows and i "send" manually decimal Longitude and Latitude to my AVD but i get the same null result in mLastLocation. Must i do sometihing else in the Emulator Control Window or in the AVD ? I read "Android Docs" but i did not find an answer. In the AVD, the Location is on and mock location is checked.